# Fetching data from external API to Google Sheets using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fetching data from an external API into a Google Sheet and it's working fine. The problem is that I need to make a kind of "loop" to bring the data I need. To exemplify, I put the OrderId at a row and the script brings the status from an API.

It works fine with the first line but what should I change on my script to make it more dynamic? Bring all the data from every row at column 'A'?

Below the piece of the script that inserts the data in the sheet:

```
function getOrder() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var order = sheet.getRange(3,1).getValue()  
var url = ("https://myendpoint.com/orders/"+order);

try
{
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url,
    {
      "headers":{
        "Accept":"application/json"
      }
    }
  );

  var fact = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(fact);

  Logger.log(data["status"]);
  sheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(data["status"]);
}
catch(error)
{ 
  Logger.log(error);
  sheet.getRange(3,2).setValue("Error"); 
}
```

I'm not a developer so I am struggling to make it work =) 
Appreciate the help

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure if I understood your problem. When you said "it works fine with the first line", are you referring to the `range(3,2)`? So each value of `data["status"]` depends of the value in column A for each row? Also, sharing an example of your Sheet would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas! Yes, you got exactly what I mean. Each value of `data["status"]  `depends of the value in column A for each row. Column A I put the orderId (3,1) and the Colunm B I return the result (OrderStatus) that depends on each row.. I think I need to make a kind of loop in the script or something to make it work for the whole column. Here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kslqZL20YUblYS8m91b9dKfa8ksDK6r88EwrJINX1Ow/edit?usp=sharing Thanks for the help

Comment: I've updated the thread with the full script I am using ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. As you guessed, this can be solved with a loop. In this case a `for` fits perfectly as it's meant to "*run the same code over and over again, each time with a different value.*" You can read about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

1. First we get the [last
   row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
   of the sheet (I'm assuming the Sheet only contains the data you
   showed).
2. Use
   [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
   to store the Order Ids in a 2D array, as `getValue` only gets the
   value of the top-left cell of the Range.
3. Declare the `url` variable each time inside the `for` loop. As you see I'm using `orders[i][0]` where `i` is the Row, and `0` is the column. If you used Column B too, the next column would be `1`. A representation of this "2D" array:

[image]

```
function getOrder(){


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //Value is 15
  var orders = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow - 2).getValues(); //Deduce 2, as it gets the values from Row 3 + 15 rows.


  for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){

    var url = ("https://myendpoint.com/orders/"+orders[i][0]);

    try 
    {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        url,
        {
          "headers":{
            "Accept":"application/json"
          }
        }
      );

      var fact = response.getContentText();
      var data = JSON.parse(fact);

      Logger.log(data["status"]);
      sheet.getRange(i+3, 2).setValue(data["status"]);

    } 
    catch(error)
    {
      Logger.log(error);
      sheet.getRange(i+3, 2).setValue("Error");
    }

  }
}
```

The rest of the code is pretty much the same, except the setValue, where we use the `i` iterator to write in the correct row. We add 3 as the array index starts at 0 but the data starts at Row 3.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and explanation, @Jescanellas =) it is working perfectly with those changes.. saved my life!